# Django TestRunner Incorrect Query Counts, Corrupted Data?? General Mayhem

Tags: django, unit-testing, nose

I've been having a very strange problem.

I have a test class that subclasses django.test.TestCase which has about 5 different tests in it.
When I run my full test suite (using nose, and specifying sqlite as backend) there are a series of failures.  When I go to debug the tests, running them individually, they pass fine.

In one of my tests I get the count of objects before adding an additional object. ex.

```
test_count = TestObject.objects.all().count()
# Add an entry to TestObject
self.assertEqual(test_count + 1, TestObject.objects.all().count()) # should pass
```

This was confusing that it would work fine when run individually but not when run with other tests.
In pdb when I look at the variables, `test_count` is equal to 1, but `TestObjects.objects.all().count()` is equal to `[]` after the first line.

```
ipdb> test_count
1
ipdb> TestObject.objects.all()
[]
ipdb> TestObject.objects.all().count()
0
```

This takes place right on the second line after assigning value to `test_count` but before adding another object to `TestObject`

When my coworker runs our tests all of his pass fine.

Has anyone experienced things of this nature before? I have tried to change the variable names, I thought maybe there was a conflict somewhere.  I am all out of ideas. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does it work fine if you delete all TestObjects in your TestCase's tearDown() method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the SO post, you're seeing TestObject.objects.all().count()
return two different values on successive calls.

That is basically impossible unless there's something else getting in there
and doing stuff to your db.

Alternatively, does your subclass of TestCase correctly call
super(MyTestCase, self).setUp() and other superclass methods to get the DB
setup right?

Malcolm

posted from django-users